# Exact same neural-network code producing different results

Tags: python, visual-studio, machine-learning, neural-network

I am currently going through the first chapter of [Michael Nielsen's neural network book.](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html)

I am running into an anomaly where the exact same code is producing wildly different results, with the only difference between the code being where it is copied from. One set of code is the one which I wrote as I went through the chapter, and the other set is from copying Nielsen's source code from github. Naturally, his works and mine doesn't. Nonetheless, if you plug both blocks of code into a [text comparing tool](https://www.textcompare.org/python/), you can see that they're the exact same, save for a few comments.

The code is building a basic neural network that seeks to identify handwritten digits. The code runs epochs in the neural network, and then outputs how many numbers are correctly identified in each epoch.

Given the current parameters, each epoch should produce roughly 8000 to 9500 out of 10,000 correct results, and this result is printed to the terminal. This is what you will consistently observe when Nielsen's code is ran.

Conversely, when the same code is ran, but copied from my file, the results are consistently ~50-450 out of 10,000.

Perhaps this is something to do with VS code? I'm really at a loss for why the same code to the letter is producing different results. I was hoping someone smarter than me would know why it matters where you ctrl-c ctrl-v from. Thanks!

Here is the code I wrote:

```html
#mine
import random
import numpy as np

class Network(object):

    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                        for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

    def feedforward(self, a):
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
            return a

    def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta, 
            test_data=None):
        if test_data: n_test = len(test_data)
        n = len(training_data)
        for j in range(epochs):
            random.shuffle(training_data)
            mini_batches = [
                training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]
                for k in range(0, n, mini_batch_size)]
            for mini_batch in mini_batches:
                self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)
            if test_data:
                print("Epoch {0}: {1} / {2}".format(
                    j, self.evaluate(test_data), n_test))
            else:
                print("Epoch {0} complete".format(j))
            
    def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
        nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        for x, y in mini_batch:
            delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)
            nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
            nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
        self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                        for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
        self.biases = [b-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nb
                       for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

    def backprop(self, x, y):
        nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        activation = x
        activations = [x]
        zs = []
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            z = np.dot(w, activation)+b
            zs.append(z)
            activation = sigmoid(z)
            activations.append(activation)
        delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \
            sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
        nabla_b[-1] = delta
        nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())

        for l in range(2, self.num_layers):
            z = zs[-l]
            sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
            delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l+1].transpose(), delta) * sp
            nabla_b[-l] = delta
            nabla_w[-l] = np.dot(delta, activations[-l-1].transpose())
        return (nabla_b, nabla_w)

    def evaluate(self, test_data):
        test_results = [(np.argmax(self.feedforward(x)), y)
                        for (x, y) in test_data]
        return sum(int(x == y) for (x, y) in test_results)

    def cost_derivative(self, output_activations, y):
        return (output_activations-y)

### Non Network functions
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_prime(z):
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))
```

And here is the code that he wrote:

```html
#his
import random
import numpy as np

class Network(object):

    def __init__(self, sizes):

        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                        for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

    def feedforward(self, a):
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
        return a

    def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta,
            test_data=None):
        if test_data: n_test = len(test_data)
        n = len(training_data)
        for j in range(epochs):
            random.shuffle(training_data)
            mini_batches = [
                training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]
                for k in range(0, n, mini_batch_size)]
            for mini_batch in mini_batches:
                self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)
            if test_data:
                print("Epoch {0}: {1} / {2}".format(
                    j, self.evaluate(test_data), n_test))
            else:
                print("Epoch {0} complete".format(j))

    def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
        nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        for x, y in mini_batch:
            delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y)
            nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
            nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
        self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw
                        for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
        self.biases = [b-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nb
                       for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

    def backprop(self, x, y):
        nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
        nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        activation = x
        activations = [x] 
        zs = [] 
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            z = np.dot(w, activation)+b
            zs.append(z)
            activation = sigmoid(z)
            activations.append(activation)
        delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \
            sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
        nabla_b[-1] = delta
        nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())
        for l in range(2, self.num_layers):
            z = zs[-l]
            sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
            delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l+1].transpose(), delta) * sp
            nabla_b[-l] = delta
            nabla_w[-l] = np.dot(delta, activations[-l-1].transpose())
        return (nabla_b, nabla_w)

    def evaluate(self, test_data):
        test_results = [(np.argmax(self.feedforward(x)), y)
                        for (x, y) in test_data]
        return sum(int(x == y) for (x, y) in test_results)

    def cost_derivative(self, output_activations, y):
        return (output_activations-y)

#### Miscellaneous functions
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_prime(z):
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))
```

Below is the helper file and the main file. The number image data used can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/tree/master/data).

helper:

```html
"""
mnist_loader
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

A library used to load mnist data.
"""

#### Libraries
# Standard library
import pickle
import gzip

# Third party libraries
import numpy as np

def load_data():
    """Returns the MNIST data as a tuple containing the training data,
    the validation data, and the test data.

    The ``training_data`` is returned as a tuple with two entries.
    The first entry contains the actual training images.  This is a
    numpy ndarray with 50,000 entries.  Each entry is, in turn, a
    numpy ndarray with 784 values, representing the 28 * 28 = 784
    pixels in a single MNIST image.

    The second entry in the ``training_data`` tuple is a numpy ndarray
    containing 50,000 entries.  Those entries are just the digit
    values (0...9) for the corresponding images contained in the first
    entry of the tuple.

    The ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are similar, except
    each contains only 10,000 images.

    This is a nice data format, but for use in neural networks it's
    helpful to modify the format of the ``training_data`` a little.
    That's done in the wrapper function ``load_data_wrapper()``, see
    below.
    """
    f = gzip.open('./data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    u = pickle._Unpickler( f )
    u.encoding = 'latin1'
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = u.load()
    # training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return(training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():

    """Return a tuple containing ``(training_data, validation_data,
    test_data)``. Based on ``load_data``, but the format is more
    convenient for use in our implementation of neural networks.

    In particular, ``training_data`` is a list containing 50,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  ``x`` is a 784-dimensional numpy.ndarray
    containing the input image.  ``y`` is a 10-dimensional
    numpy.ndarray representing the unit vector corresponding to the
    correct digit for ``x``.

    ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are lists containing 10,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  In each case, ``x`` is a 784-dimensional
    numpy.ndarry containing the input image, and ``y`` is the
    corresponding classification, i.e., the digit values (integers)
    corresponding to ``x``.

    Obviously, this means we're using slightly different formats for
    the training data and the validation / test data.  These formats
    turn out to be the most convenient for use in our neural network
    code."""

    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = list(zip(training_inputs, training_results))
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = list(zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1]))
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = list(zip(test_inputs, te_d[1]))
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def vectorized_result(j):
    """Return a 10-dimensional unit vector with a 1.0 in the jth position
    and zeroes elsewhere. This converts a a digit (0...9) into a 
    corresponding desired output from the neural network.
    """
    e = np.zeros((10, 1))
    e[j] = 1.0
    return e
```

main:

```html
import mnist_loader
training_data, validation_data, test_data = mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()

import test #change this to test2 to check nielsens code
net = test.Network([784, 30, 10]) # change here too
net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 3.0, test_data=test_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

So they weren't "eXacTLy tHe SaME". The difference was in the for loop of the feedforward function. I was returning at every iteration, which was incorrect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).